# SAS collapse dates

Tags: variables, group-by, sas, aggregate

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
cust date 1 2 3... 600
1    1    5 . . ... .
1    2    5 . . ... .
1    2    . 4 . ... .
1    2    . . 6 ... .
2    1    1 . . ... .
2    1    . 5 . ... .
2    2    . . . ... 10
```

I want to collapse variables 1 to 600 for each date by customer (cust), so that the dataset looks like this:

```
cust date 1 2 3... 600
1    1    5 . . ... .
1    2    5 4 6 ... .
2    1    1 5 . ... .
2    2    . . . ... 10
```

I started with the following code (maybe it's a bit complicated), and it doesn't work:

```
data want ;
set have;
array vars &list.; *stored array of variables 1-600;
retain count vars;
by cust date;
if first.date then do;
do _i=1 to dim(vars);
vars[_i]=.; 
end;
count=0;
end;
count=count+1;
vars[_1]=vars;
if last.date then do;
output;
end;
drop count;
run;
```

Do you have any idea? Another idea was to use proc expand, but it doesn't work either because the dates are duplicates.

Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a neat trick to achieve this using the UPDATE statement.  The first reference to the existing table (with the obs=0) creates an empty table with the required structure, the second reference updates with the values.  The BY statement ensures it only outputs one record per BY value.  Hope this makes sense.

```
data have;
input cust date v1 v2 v3 v600;
datalines;
1    1    5 . . .
1    2    5 . . .
1    2    . 4 . .
1    2    . . 6 .
2    1    1 . . .
2    1    . 5 . .
2    2    . . . 10
;
run;

data want;
update have (obs=0) have;
by cust date;
run;
```

Comment: @Joe, at least it's not the Pete Best! ;-)

Comment: @ Keith thank you so much! This is really helpful statement! Works perfectly!!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use RETAIN with the variables coming in from the dataset on the `set` statement; or more accurately, you can, but it won't work - variables are `RETAIN`ed automatically on variables from set statements.  They are also, however, overwritten by the next iteration of the data step when the `set` occurs.

You can either use a temporary array to store the retained values and copy it back over when `last.date` (temporary arrays are also retained automatically, FYI), or you can use a different technique entirely - hash tables, SQL, whatever you're most familiar with.

For example,

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
  select cust, date, sum(var1) as var1, sum(var2) as var2, ... 
  from have
  group by cust,date;
quit;
```

You would want to construct the `sum(var1) as var1` in a macro variable, something like

```
%macro sumvar(var=)
sum(&var.) as &var.
%mend sumvar;
proc sql;
select cats('%sumvar(var=',name,')') 
  into :sumlist separated by ','
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE' and not (name in ('CUST','DATE'))
;
quit;
```

and then use that &sumlist. in the sql above.

```
select cust, date, &sumlist.
```

This is probably the easiest to code; it's probably not as efficient as other options if you have really large data.

Answer (score 2):

You could so something like the following:

```
proc means data=have noprint;
  by cust date;
  var &list;
  output out=want(drop=_:) sum=;
run;
```

Comment: Good idea.  You probably should change `by` to `class` unless the data is guaranteed sorted (to avoid having to sort).

Comment: Thanks, the reason I chose the by was because there was a by in the sample data step so I figured it's probably sorted.